# Which clause is in bold below?

Tags: clauses, appositives, attributives

> Davidson’s article is one of a number of pieces that have recently appeared making the point that **the reason we have such stubbornly high unemployment and declining middle-class incomes today** is largely because of the big drop in demand because of the Great Recession, but it is also because of the advances in both globalization and the information technology revolution, which are more rapidly than ever replacing labor with machines or foreign workers.

What is the subordinate clause in the bolded sentence above?

1. I think it's an appositional clause, because the following **we have such stubbornly high unemployment and declining middle-class incomes today** has no shortage of elements.
2. But the teacher thought it was an attributive clause and omitted that. Because the apposition clause cannot omit that.  But in the attributive clause, why is "that" not a component?